# Modern tactics for a short sighted species

Tags: warfare

How would a short sighted species fight humans? For the sake of the question, these creatures are the same as humans, its just that they cannot see past 500 feet, and their weapons cannot hurt anything further than that. They have a better sense of hearing and smell, however.

Each side has the same tech, and this takes place in 2017. It takes place on Earth, but the creatures have access to the same maps as we do.

I had a notion they would try their best to try and stick to fighting urban battles, but is there more tactics they would have to change in order to effectively fight humans? I am looking for places and fighting styles which would minimize their handicap, as the urban fighting setting mentioned above.

Comment: What is these species natural habitat? Why they can't see past 500 feet? Are they advanced enough to know about glasses?

Comment: Their home planet has a very dense fog, and so their eyes cannot see effectively past this point. Technically they can see further, but they only see blobs at that distance. They have not developed glasses yet, because they have not needed them until now. They rely on sound, smell, and sight in conjunction.

Comment: 1. Get glasses. 2. Fix problem with weaponry. 3. Win. So, why this wouldn't be possible?

Comment: You need to elaborate on the scenario. There is way too many open questions before answering this. You said "modern", but what is their scientific progress like? What age are we even talking? When they lack scientific progress and current year military comes over they have just lost. You need to specify those things in your question.

Comment: If these creatures have to fight on Earth, which is mostly fog-free, they would be at a real disadvantage. Given that they are not technologically advanced, I don't see any scenario how they can win. But if they fight on their planet, it is humans that would have to adapt.

Comment: @Alexander we already have adapted. From ages (literally) smoke was everyday reality on battlefield. Gunpowder smoke, smoke screens and so on. And fog is quite similar.

Comment: @Mołot and despite ages of advancement, smoke screens still work :)

Comment: @Alexander Well, it is far, far from perfect, and your usual smoke screen would not work so good against thermovision. Not to mention our artillery, where bigger guns can simply cover small area with fire. It's not that "their weapons cannot hurt anything further"   as in the question. It's just bit harder and more expensive.

Comment: @Mołot of course, once we know where enemy is, aviation and artillery can quickly finish them. But I suspect it will be "hide and seek" battle, and not sure how effective thermovision will be in the fog at distances over 500 feet.

Comment: @Alexander with question as it is, it only needs to be bit more effective than "none" at distance bit longer than 500 ft for humans to be completely safe and win every encounter ;)

Comment: Unless their eyes are much larger than ours are, the difference in focus between 500 feet and infinite is  minimal.  Indeed assuming a focal length of 30 mm and a pupil diameter of 7mm (dusk) focusing on 25 feet everything is in focus from 12 feet to infinity.  Google hyperfocal distance

Comment: @SherwoodBotsford exactly my thought when I read "500 foot".

Comment: We do not see all the way to the horizon or into infinity with precision. The further something is from us, the less defined the image becomes. Snipers attach scopes to  their rifles to allow them to see distant targets more accurately. We have also developed telescopes (though in a fogged environment, these will probably be less useful)|. But we have developed sonar, radar and other methods to allow us to see farther and even "through" solid objects. I think your species would surely have learnt or evolved some compensation to limiting vision.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not much would change once you got up to the point of WW1. Just because you have difficulty seeing an enemy doesn't stop you pointing weapons at him.

Russia and America have hundreds of ICBMs pointed at each other. The missiles have no line of sight to their targets and neither do their operators, they don't need satellites to work, dead reckoning and gyros can do the job.

Prior to that, then the obvious first step would be to develop tech that would get around the short sightedness. Longbowmen (or their equivalent) might work with "spotters" equipped with telescopes for example.

Long range weaponry might have an accelerated development in your world. Once you've overcome a disadvantage that everyone suffers from, then you've got a hell of an edge. The development of powered flight in our own world is a good example. Once it became possible then every army in the world wanted to be able to fly. Likewise in your world, once it becomes possible to see and accurately target an enemy more than 1km away, then every army will develop that technology.

Comment: Nice! Will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Mountain fighting, jungle fighting. A keener sense of hearing and smell both would be very helpful in these environments - maybe even more than in urban environments where mechanical noise and pollutants nullify the hearing and smell advantages.

If you picked a place on the edge of both worlds (Rio or Argentina), you might have the tension of places important to humanity wrapped in territory that humankind is at a disadvantage in.

As others have commented the condition is correctable with lenses: glasses, indirect fire (remote sensors), or other magnification equipment.

Answer (score 1):

When defending they can make sure there are not long lines of sight. Placing objects everywhere, etc.

When attacking humans who can see further it gets more difficult, if they themselves are prepared, because they would do the opposite and have long sightlines. The short-sighted ones would need to disrupt sightlines with smokescreens as people pointed out in the comments.

When they have access to current military technology they would have stuff like strike drones, etc. They just need to be able to watch a screen and not see into the distance.

In short: They will not ever stand a chance in soldier battles, but they are basically on even footing with humans in everything else, so they would not need special tactics with this.